# Error on update texlive using tlmgr

Tags: update-manager, latex, texlive

I have to update texlive, but this is what I get:

```
khaled@khaled:~$ tlmgr update --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5579.
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313768/tlmgr-unknown-directive

Comment: I got this error message in ubuntu 16.04, too. Ubuntu uses the debian `tlmgr` and tex.stackexchange.com gives an answer on using 2015 packages. But it would be helpful to know, how to update tlmgr to use the 2016 package format.

Comment: I expanded the first thread for the minimum example there. I hope we get a complete answer to the case soon.